# UI issue/glitch on privilege tracking card

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, privileges

I was tracking information about my next reputation privilege, I found this UI issue, next to expandable usercard, It's overlapping on cancel button.

**OS : Ubuntu - 16.04**

**Browser : Chrome - Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

**Zoom size : 100% (Default)**

I don't know where to submit this.

[image: Issue]

Comment: Can you please add more information, which browser, OS and zoom size?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 59 in Windows 10. It is a bug

Comment: Also reproduced on Chromium 59 and Firefox 54 in Xubuntu Linux. The font used by both browsers on my system is Arial Bold (from [MS core fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web)). Looks like the popup just isn't wide enough to accommodate the long privilege name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Fix is waiting in repo for build, so it should be live in couple hours.